# How to store which page non-signed in user arrived from in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

(1) A 'Host' share a link to a 'campaign' on the site e.g. /campaigns/17

(2) The visitor to /campaigns/17 clicks on something that is only for signed in/signed up users and is taken to the sign in/sign up page

I'm trying to get the campaign id (e.g. 17) to be stored in the new user's paramaters (for which I was thinking of using a hidden field) but am not sure how to save the id. I have thought about request.path but don't know how to carry this through to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solve this problem. I am assuming you have some type of authenticate method inside of your application controller.

Inside of your application controller, have something like the following:

```
def authenticate 
  unless current_user 
    session[:protected_destination] = request.fullpath
    flash[:notice] = "You're not logged in."
    redirect_to login_path
    return false
  end
end
```

Then, in your login logic, you must have some code like the following. For me, login happened in the UserSession controller since I use Authlogic.

```
def new
  session[:protected_destination] ||= request.referrer || root_path

  if current_user
    redirect_to session[:protected_destination]
    session[:protected_destination] = nil
  else
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end
end

def create
  @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

  if @user_session.save
    protected_destination = session[:protected_destination] || root_path
    session[:protected_destination] = nil
    redirect_to protected_destination
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

As you can see, the destination you want to go to is stored inside of the session. When you login, it checks if you were going somewhere, and then redirects you there if you were. If not, it will just take you to the root url.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I have this setup at the moment which is great. What I was hoping to add is the ability to store the 'campaign_id' in the table 'users' when the user signs up - where campaign_id is given by the campaign page that the user arrives on

Comment: Have you tried using some kind of join table? I personally favor a has, :through relationship. What you could do is create a new model, called CampaignRelation, which belongs to campaign and belongs to user. Then, in your authenticate method, if the user is not logged in, you can store the campaign id in the session. On login, if there is a campaign id in the session, then you create a new CampaignRelation that belongs to the target Campaign and the newly logged in user. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's very interesting - however, these are visitors who have not yet signed up that I'm interested in giving the right campaign id as an attribute of their user account once they sign up (ie. the campaign that they follow is given by the campaign page they first visit before becoming a member). Not sure how your solution would work in that case. Thanks!